# Disable shadowbox default loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

Is there any way where I can disable shadowbox default loading image. We need to show our company loading image only. Right now, it shows shadowbox loading image and then our loading image.

```
Shadowbox.open({
 content:$("#load_image").html(),
 player:'html',
 width:250,
 height:100,
 options:{modal:true}
});
```

Thank you

Comment: hahaha :P please add some code by editing your question :D

Comment: Do you mean customize shadowbox.js default loading image?

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions to modify the css are not bad.

Applying another image only to specific links isn't very difficult.

Give the link where you like to have the company-logo inside the Shadowbox a special className(I will use `"foo"` in this example)

Use this to initialize the Shadowbox:

```
Shadowbox.init(
                {
                  onOpen:function(){
                            if($(Shadowbox.gallery[Shadowbox.current].link)
                                .hasClass('foo')){
                                  $('html').addClass('foo');
                                }
                         },
                  onClose:function(){$('html').removeClass('foo');}
                         }
              );
```

It will check if the clicked link has the  special className `foo` .
When it does, it adds this className to the `<html>`-element.

Now you are able to apply a different image as loading-image to those specific links by using the selector:

```
html.foo #sb-loading-inner span
```

Comment: I cannot confirm this at this moment. We have already launched our site the way it is. I will probably fix it in our next phase and I will confirm if it right. But +1 for detail answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To customize the ShadowBox preloading image, edit the `background` property in the following line in `shadowbox.css`:

```
#sb-loading-inner span{background:url(loading.gif) no-repeat;padding-left:34px;display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can change the image showed by cahnging the css style in shadowbox.css or override it for the element `#sb-loading-inner span`

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qrMsL/1/

Comment: I believe if I change the css for shadowbox, it will be applied everywhere in the site. I want for specific shadowbox in the site.